# Localstorage stops working if value is to high

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a game. I have fixed a problem with numbers but now I have a new problem.

If a user goes past a certain number it stops adding it to the localstorage. See http://beefinc.tk and change the localstorage value to 9000000000000000000 and it stops letting you a +1 to the value. If you do go to that number and click the red button with a cow it say `NaN` where the your money is. So, I was wondering how to fix this. Below is my code.

```
var money = null;

if (localStorage.getItem('money')) {
    var money = nFormatter(localStorage.getItem('money'), 1);
    $$("#moneyCount").html(money);
} else {
    var money = localStorage.setItem('money', '0');
    $$("#moneyCount").html(money);
}

$$(".beefButton").on('click', function() {
    var money = localStorage.getItem('money');
    money++;
    localStorage.setItem('money', money);
    $$("#moneyCount").html(nFormatter(localStorage.getItem('money'), 1));
    setColor('Checking For Achievements', "#ed7032", "font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;");
    var money = localStorage.getItem('money');
    if(money === '100') {
        setColor('Found 100', "#ed7032", "font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;");
        setColor('Displaying Entrepreneur Achievement!', "#ed7032", "font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;");
        beefinc.addNotification({
            message: 'Become an Entrepreneur'
        });
    }
    if(money === '1000') {
        setColor('Found 1000', "#ed7032", "font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;");
        setColor('Displaying Business Man Achievement!', "#ed7032", "font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;");
        beefinc.addNotification({
            message: 'Become an Business Man'
        });
    }
    if(money === '1000000') {
        setColor('Found 1000000', "#ed7032", "font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;");
        setColor('Displaying Millionaire Achievement!', "#ed7032", "font-weight: bold; font-size: 20px;");
        beefinc.addNotification({
            message: 'Become an Millionaire'
        });
    }

    start = clicks = frequency = 0
        if (!start) {
            start = new Date;
            frequency = ++clicks / (new Date - start) * 1000;

        } 


});

function nFormatter(num, digits) {
  var si = [
    { value: 1E33, symbol: "D"},
    { value: 1E30, symbol: "N"},
    { value: 1E27, symbol: "O"},
    { value: 1E24, symbol: "Y"},
    { value: 1E21, symbol: "Z" },
    { value: 1E18, symbol: "E" },
    { value: 1E15, symbol: "P" },
    { value: 1E12, symbol: "T" },
    { value: 1E9,  symbol: "B" },
    { value: 1E6,  symbol: "M" },
    { value: 1E3,  symbol: "K" }
  ], rx = /\.0+$|(\.[0-9]*[1-9])0+$/, i;
  for (i = 0; i < si.length; i++) {
    if (num >= si[i].value) {
      return (num / si[i].value).toFixed(digits).replace(rx, "$1") + si[i].symbol;
    }
  }
  return num.toFixed(digits).replace(rx, "$1");
}
```

So I know I use $$ instead of $ but that's because I use a framework called Framework7 which has its on built in version of jQuery but it works exactly like it.

Comment: 9000000000000000001 is way larger than the [maximum safe integer value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) JavaScript supports (which is 9007199254740991).

Answer (score 3):

You are exceeding the max value of number supported by ECMA Script which is

> +/- 9007199254740991

Read documentation [Numbers](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_8.5) and [Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MAX_SAFE_INTEGER)

Comment: @Iceman, may be they didn't get to root of the problem, don't get dishearten the downvotes

Comment: is there a way to bypass that number? Cause if i cant go past there then really the game does have an end not and infinite game like it is suppossed to be...

Comment: @JoeShenton, You can take a look at [bignumber.js](https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/)

Comment: I had a look and i don't really understand how is changes the Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER

Answer (score 2):

Using  `Number` type og Javascript largest exact integral value is 2^(53)-1, or `9007199254740991`. In ES6, this is defined as `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`

You can try libraries like big.js for handling even bigger numbers.